# Get list of methods/functions defined explicitly in a module

Tags: perl, code-coverage

After realizing the sad state of code coverage on our unit tests at work I am trying to create  a utility that will scan our code base and flag files that don't have 100%. I found two approaches that get all of the methods:

Access symbol table directly:

```
for my $classname ( @ARGV ) {
   eval "require $classname";
   die "Can't load $classname $EVAL_ERROR"
      if $EVAL_ERROR; 

    no strict 'refs';
    METHODS:
    for my $sym ( keys %{ "${classname}::" } ) {
       next METHODS unless defined &{"${classname}::${sym}"};
       print "$sym\n";
   }
}
```

Use the [`Class::Inspector`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class%3A%3AInspector) module from CPAN:

```
for my $classname ( @ARGV ) {
   my @methods = Class::Inspector->methods($classname, 'public');
   print Dumper \@methods;
}
```

these two approaches produce similar results; The problem with these is that they show *all* of the methods available to the entire module, not just the methods defined *inside* of that module.

Is there some way to distinguish between methods accessible to a module and methods defined explicitly inside of a module?

Note: I am not attempting to create a full code coverage test, for my use case I just want to test that all of the methods have been called at least once. Complete coverage tests like [`Devel::Cover`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3A%3ACover) are overkill for us.

Comment: I can't verify this at the moment, but I think you need [`can`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#The-UNIVERSAL-Class):
`print "$_\n" for grep $classname->can( $_ ), keys %{"${classname}::}"`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately `can` seems to still look up the inheritance tree. I am still getting entries for `Dumper` and other methods from some of our custom modules.

Comment: You could call `local @PACKAGE::NAME::INC = ();` and then do the `can()` check.

Comment: Just run `Devel::Cover` and reduce down the report afterwards. It will be less effort and more accurate than building your own coverage measure (even a lightweight one), and you can expand into caring about deeper coverage metrics later on without having to throw it all away.

Comment: @NeilSlater As unreasonable as it sounds, that is just not the type of testing we do. For reference, we don't even `use Moose;` (Perl pun intended). Going forward I am going to push for these things, but right now it is unneeded.

Comment: @frezik I am still getting modules that are included via use statement after I execute `local @{ "${classname}::INC } = ();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each sub (or more specifically, each CV), remembers which package it was originally declared in. Test case:

`Foo.pm`:

```
package Foo;
sub import {
  *{caller . "::foo"} = sub{};
}
1;
```

`Bar.pm`:

```
package Bar;
use Foo;

our $bar;  # introduces *Bar::bar which does not have a CODE slot
sub baz {}
1;
```

Accessing the symbol table now gives both `foo` and `baz`. By the way, I'd write that code like this (for reasons that will become clear in a moment):

```
my $classname = 'Bar';
for my $glob (values %{ "${classname}::" }) {
   my $sub = *$glob{CODE} or next;
   say *$glob{NAME};
}
```

Next, we have to look into the [`B` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/B) to introspect the [underlying C data structure](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RURBAN/illguts-0.42/index-14.html#cv). We do this with the `B::svref_2object` function. This will produce a `B::CV` object which has the convenient `STASH` field (which returns a `B::HV` object which has a `NAME` field):

```
use B ();
my $classname = 'Bar';
for my $glob (values %{ "${classname}::" }) {
   my $sub = *$glob{CODE} or next;
   my $cv = B::svref_2object($sub);
   $cv->STASH->NAME eq $classname or next;
   say *$glob{NAME};
}
```

Add a few sanity checks, and this should work quite well.

Dynamic class/module loading should not be done via string `eval`. Instead I recommend [`Module::Runtime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module%3a%3aRuntime):

```
Module::Runtime::require_module($classname);
```

Comment: This is exactly the type of approach I was looking for, thanks! Some of the calls to `NAME` are return objects of `B::special`, it's unclear from the documentation what that means, but I will just skip over them since they all appear to come from higher up the inheritance tree